# html no error message displayed

Tags: php, html, message

Good evening everybody,

We are beginners and unskilled in php html ...

this is the page which will allow us to display the books available to borrow them. For now we are at the stage display books. No error message is displayed, but the list of books is not displayed either.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.3.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Client :  127.0.0.1
-- Généré le :  Jeu 14 Mai 2015 à 19:02
-- Version du serveur :  5.6.24
-- Version de PHP :  5.6.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Base de données :  `bibliotheque`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `livres`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `livres` (
  `ID_LIVRE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NOM_LIVRE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `AUTEUR` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `DATE_PARUTION` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PSEUDO_POSSESSEUR` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ETAT` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Contenu de la table `livres`
--

INSERT INTO `livres` (`ID_LIVRE`, `NOM_LIVRE`, `AUTEUR`, `DATE_PARUTION`, `PSEUDO_POSSESSEUR`, `ETAT`) VALUES
(5, 'Les fleurs du mal ', 'Charles Baudelaire', 1857, 'victor', 1),
(6, 'Les Misérables ', 'Victor Hugo', 1862, 'victor', 1),
(7, 'Les Liaisons dangereuses', 'Choderlos de Laclos', 1782, 'victor', 1),
(8, 'Madame Bovary', 'Gustave Flaubert ', 1857, 'victor', 1),
(9, 'Voyage au bout de la nuit', 'Céline ', 1932, 'victor', 1),
(10, 'Le Petit Prince ', 'Antoine de Saint-Exupéry', 1943, 'victor', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `utilisateurs`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `utilisateurs` (
  `ID_UTILISATEURS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NOM` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PRENOM` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PSEUDO` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `MDP` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Contenu de la table `utilisateurs`
--

INSERT INTO `utilisateurs` (`ID_UTILISATEURS`, `NOM`, `PRENOM`, `PSEUDO`, `MDP`, `EMAIL`) VALUES
(5, 'Mestiri', 'Taieb', 'mlazyscientist', '8673c156d028f0dddaf6cd2d0f3e3dc092c336de', 'mestiritaieb@gmail.com'),
(7, 'lauret', 'victor', 'victor', '563ff5da92544f70988a942d45d086496003a092', 'victorlauret@gmail.com');

--
-- Index pour les tables exportées
--

--
-- Index pour la table `livres`
--
ALTER TABLE `livres`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_LIVRE`);

--
-- Index pour la table `utilisateurs`
--
ALTER TABLE `utilisateurs`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_UTILISATEURS`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT pour les tables exportées
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT pour la table `livres`
--
ALTER TABLE `livres`
  MODIFY `ID_LIVRE` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT pour la table `utilisateurs`
--
ALTER TABLE `utilisateurs`
  MODIFY `ID_UTILISATEURS` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Now the PHP code:

```
<?php
    // Démarrage de la session
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
        <title>La Bibliothéque MLC</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="div_mere">
            <img  class="img1" src="../images/man216.png" />
            <h1>La Bibliothéque MLC</h1>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="accueil_membre.html"> Accueil </a></li>
                <li><a href="f_ajout_livre.html"> Ajouter un Document  </a></li>
                <li><a href="bdd_livres.html"> Emprunter un Document </a></li>  
                <li><a href="deconnexion.html"> Déconnexion </a></li>
            </ul>

            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/taieb.mestiri">
                <img class="facebook" src="../images/facebook29.png" />
            </a>

            <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/101730232507385912281/posts">
                <img class="gmail" src="../images/email118.png" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="div_general">
             <?php include("bdd_livres.php"); ?>        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    try {
        // On se connecte à MySQL
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bibliotheque;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        // En cas d'erreur, on affiche un message et on arrête tout
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    // On récupère tout le contenu de la table livres
    $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM livres');

    // On affiche chaque entrée une à une
    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
        echo $donnees['NOM_LIVRE'], $donnees['AUTEUR'], $donnees['DATE_PARUTION'],$donnees['PSEUDO_POSSESSEUR']  
    }

    $reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête
?>
```

Comment: would you please mind separating sql queries at the top and php code, and then try running php code?

Comment: It appears that you retyped the code and didn't copy and paste exactly what you have in your real code because the echo in your while loop does not end with a ;. When I run it as best I can on my machine, I get a syntax error that it expects a ; and sees a }. Therefore, you are either getting an error in your error log (not on the page - in the error log) or you have a ; in your code and there is a different typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above, you need a semicolon, ";" at the end of line 79:

```
echo $donnees['NOM_LIVRE'], $donnees['AUTEUR'], $donnees['DATE_PARUTION'],$donnees['PSEUDO_POSSESSEUR'];
```

After adding this, I was able to successfully run your script and see the books available.

Comment: Les fleurs du mal Charles Baudelaire1857victorLes Mis?rables Victor Hugo1862victorLes Liaisons dangereusesChoderlos de Laclos1782victorMadame BovaryGustave Flaubert 1857victorVoyage au bout de la nuitC?line 1932victorLe Petit Prince Antoine de Saint-Exup?ry1943victor

Comment: You may wish to add some formatting ;-)

Comment: Even with adding the : echo $donnees['NOM_LIVRE'], $donnees['AUTEUR'], $donnees['DATE_PARUTION'],$donnees['PSEUDO_POSSESSEUR'];  I can't see any books in my page ...

Comment: There is my html : <div class="div_general">
   
    <?php include("bdd_livres.php"); ?>   
   
  </div>

Comment: So, the PHP you show is the contents of "bdd_lives.php"?

Are you sure it is being included as expected?  I might try:

    ini_set("display_errors", TRUE);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

     require_once("bdd_lives.php")